# Rename category in permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm looking for a way to rename a category in the permalink of a WordPress site.

I currently have this:

http://mywebsite.com/category/some-blog-post/

I want this:

http://mywebsite.com/company-news/some-blog-post/

I found a way to do it via .htaccess file, but I would prefere not to do it, because it temporarily lowers PageRank. Is there a way to do it on backend?

Comment: you could get along with some googling.. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rename-category-slug-in-url

Answer (score 0):

To change it go to Settings » Permalinks and scroll down to Optional. There you will see a form to change category base and tag base. For example you can change `http://www.example.com/category/your-category-slug/` to `http://www.example.com/new-category-base/your-category-slug/`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to settings/permalinks and just change the category base name and it goes the same for tags.  here is a screenshot:
http://webmasteradvise.com/wordpress/rename-category-and-tag-slug-in-permalink/